# How to break the inner while(cin>>s2) loop without breaking the outter while(cin>>s1) loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

Please consider the C++ code below:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun1() {
  cout << "Calling fun1" << endl;
}
void fun2() {
  cout << "Calling fun2" << endl;
}

int main() {
  string s1, s2;
  while (cin >> s1) {
    fun1();
    while (cin >> s2) {
      fun2();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code has two nested while loops, in the outer while loop, use `cin` to input a value and calling `fun1`; then came into the inner while loop, use `cin` to input a value and calling `fun2`. But when I wanted to terminate the inner while loop by `ctrl` + `d`, I found the outer while loop also terminated. I know I can used the code snippet below to solve this problem, but I want to know why does the above happen? Thanks in advance.

```
  while (cin >> s1) {
    if (s1 == "end1")
      break;
    fun1();
    while (cin >> s2) {
      if (s2 == "end2")
        break;
      fun2();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The use of `ctrl-D` (or `ctrl-Z` on Windows) to close the standard input is entirely external to your program - it's not the result of code that the compiler puts into your executable, it's the result of the operating system doing its thing. This is really a question about how your computer works, not a question about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I want to know why does the above happen?

When you press `Ctrl-D` (`Ctrl-Z` on Windows) you close the stream, hence `std::cin` status returns false and internal loop terminated. As you use the same stream - `std::cin` in both loops and stream is closed already it would terminate them all, as this state is persistent. Viable solution is not to close but use some marker to terminate the internal loop so it would not affect external one, as what you did in the second example.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I have known the reason!

Comment: `std::cin::clear` may clean error condition like read wrong data. You cannot reopen it this way, it is not reversable.

Comment: I have tried to make `std::cin` valid again by `cin.clear`, but the external loop still terminated. Did I do something wrong? The code snippet is below:
```C++
  while (cin >> s1) {
    fun1();
    while (cin >> s2) {
      fun2();
    }
    cin.clear();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried again, use the code snippet above did work!  ```while (cin >> s1) {
    fun1();
    while (cin >> s2) {
      fun2();
    }
    cin.clear();
  }```. Maybe I did something wrong last time.